# SEO - Website relaunch. Is it wiser to change things gradually?

Tags: seo, google, wordpress

I'm about to do a website relaunch in a couple of months. It's a WordPress site. The relaunch will include these changes:

- changes in content, both text and images
- a new WP theme, thus changes in the DOM as well as design changes
- some minor structural changes

The domain luckily stays the same.

In terms of SEO I remember reading somewhere, **that it is wiser to not change everything at once**, but rather do changes gradually. Especially to not make changes with the content and the design/DOM at the same time. But I cannot find that same advise anymore anywhere.

**So my question is:** Is it better for your Google rankings to do all the above changes at once, or do them gradually, hence changing the theme first, than waiting 4 weeks or so and then doing changes to the content?

Comment: Sorry but the questions you've asked have been asked several times before in separate questions already on Pro Webmasters. (design changes, url changes and content changes).

Comment: To save you time... Google/Bing don't care about the design of your site as long as it renders correctly. Google/Bing appreciate a slow-drip/fast-drip on page updates, so you will benefit from gradually, or all at once. Google/Bing does not care about structure changes assuming you are following best practices e.g 301 redirects.